# Does the function signature indicate that processor argument returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This method signature indicates that the method takes a function (processor) which returns a promise?  And the method itself returns a promise too (this I am more sure of).

--> this:    processor: (transaction: Transaction) => Promise

```
    static async transaction<T>(processor: (transaction: Transaction) => Promise<T> ): Promise<T> {

    return (await dso.client.transaction(async (conn) => {
      const trans = new Transaction(conn);
      return await processor(trans);
    })) as T;
  }
```

Comment: `processor: (transaction: Transaction) => Promise` means that one of the parameters is called `processor` and the type of it is ` (transaction: Transaction) => Promise` or a function that takes a `Transaction` and returns `Promise`.

Comment: Okay, it takes a type which consist of a function which takes  a transaction. The subtle information 'type' brings in there. Thank you.